# bounces from verizon.net with no email address

Tags: email

Every time I send an email to my subscriber list, I get a bounce from verzion.net (with an "over quota" error), but it does not say anywhere in the bounce message what the email address was that triggered the bounce.  I would like to have a "clean" list and remove any addresses that bounce.  How can I deal with this?  Here's part of the bounce (with my domain replaced with `myserver.com`):

```
Your message cannot be delivered to the following recipients:

  Recipient address: @resst169053v.mailsrvcs.net:resx595p@ims-ms-daemon
  Original address: everyone-list-7630@myserver.com
  Reason: LMTP transmission failure has occurred
  Diagnostic code: lmtp;550 5.2.2 Delivery failed: Over quota
  Remote system: dns;resst169053v.mailsrvcs.net (TCP|172.19.172.47|58773|172.19.169.54|225)
```

Answer (score 1):

Does your mailing list software support [VERP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_envelope_return_path)? Most all of them do. VERP is the canonical answer to these types of issues - it encodes the recipient's email address into the envelope sender's address. This way when there's a bounce, it's sent back, and you can tell who the original recipient was by looking at what email address the NDR was sent to.

Answer (score 0):

If you can specify the email addresses you send out to, you can narrow it down exponentially by halving your list.

Send a message to half your list. If the address doesn't bounce, it's not in that half. Repeat. For 1,000,000 addresses, this will take you about 20 total messages.

Comment: But won't that annoy them?

Comment: Not if you do it as part of the normal mailings